# Implementing Interfaces in Dynamic Classes Using Java's Unsafe

Tags: java, interface

I'm trying to load classes dynamically using Java's sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(String name, byte[] code, int off, int len, ClassLoader classLoader, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain), but for some reason the Objects I create by calling Class.newInstance() (or Class.getConstructor().newInstance()) are not instances of an interface that I have implemented in that class (and which Class.getInterfaces() returns).

The method I have defined to load a class given bytecode is this:

```
public static Class<?> loadClass(String name, URL url, byte[] code) {
    Unsafe u = UnsafeKey.getUnsafe();

    java.lang.ClassLoader loader = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    Permissions perms=new Permissions();
    perms.add(new RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers"));
    ProtectionDomain protection = new ProtectionDomain(new CodeSource(url,(Certificate[])null),perms);

    return u.defineClass(name, code, 0, code.length, loader, protection);
}
```

The bytecode in my case is loaded directly from a .class file (compiled by my jdk) using this method:

```
public static Class<?> loadClass(String name, File f) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    InputStream i = new FileInputStream(f);
    i.read(data);
    return loadClass(name, f.toURI().toURL(), data);
}
```

Which sends the loaded data to the first method.

The class I'm using for testing implements an interface called PixelArtist:

```
import com.ralitski.art.api.PixelArtist;

public class PixelArtistTest implements PixelArtist {

    public PixelArtistTest() {}

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColor(int x, int y) {
        int z = x * y;
        return x + (y * 255) + z;
    }
}
```

After loading this class from the file, defining it, and creating a new instance, I attempt to use it with this method (this object passed is created by a call to Class.newInstance()):

```
private static Artist getArtist(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o);
    Class c = o.getClass();
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(c.getSuperclass());
    for(Class c2 : c.getInterfaces()) {
        System.out.println("    " + c2);
    }
    System.out.println(PixelArtist.class.isInstance(o));
    if(o instanceof Artist) {
        System.out.println(1);
        return (Artist)o;
    } else if(o instanceof PixelArtist) {
        System.out.println(2);
        return new PixelArtistFeed((PixelArtist)o);
    } else {
        System.out.println(3);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The output of that code is this:

```
PixelArtistTest@1947c6b
class PixelArtistTest
class java.lang.Object
    interface com.ralitski.art.api.PixelArtist
false
3
```

As you can see, the Class lists PixelArtist as an interface, but the object created from that class is not an instance of type PixelArtist.

I have tried adding different permissions to the class when I define it (even an AllPermission) and I have tried instantiating the Object using Class.getConstructor().newInstance(), but this error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are loading the class into the system class loader. This class loader doesn't have your interface, or has another copy of the interface which has a different class loader, most likely your class loader.

I suggest you use your default class loader instead e.g. the same one as the `PixelArtist.class.getClassLoader()`